# Passing variable in class methods

Tags: java

I need to pass `t1` and  `t2` in the method of a class in java . I have shown only relevant parts .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int hr,min,secs;
       Time t1;
       t1 = new Time();
       t1.hr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the time(hours)"));
       Time t2;
       t2 = new Time();
       t2.hr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the time(hours)"));
}
```

The class is shown bellow

```
class Time {
    int hr;
    int add2times(int t1, int t2) {
        int result_hr = t1.hr + t2.hr;
    }
}
```

I get the following error  `int result_hr = t1.hr + t2.hr;` 
`int cannot be deference`

Comment: If `t1` and `t2` are `int`s, then they aren't `Time`s, and won't have a `hr` field.

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration of that method be something like `public static int  add2times(Time t1, Time t2)`?  You want `t1` and `t2` to be `Time` objects, right?

Comment: At lest read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is saying that t1 and t2 are not objects and do not have the `hr` variable, this is because objects t1 and t2 are `Time` objects and thus need to be declared as such in the arguments. You are currently defining them as int.

Your `add2Times` method is also not returning the resulting time. I have fixed that.

```
int add2times(Time t1, Time t2) {
    return t1.hr + t2.hr;
}
```

Comment: That method really should be declared `static`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I know. But this isn't Code Review.

Comment: Yes, but whenever you answer a question on Stack Overflow,  you're teaching someone something.  It's much better if you teach them something correct.  If you _know_ that this should be declared `static`, then you could edit your answer to add the word `static`, and a short explanation.  Then your answer would be much better.